# Enable TLS 1.2 on .NET 4.5.1

Tags: .net, ssl, tls1.2

A lot of articles seem to suggest adding the following registry keys to enable TLS 1.2 on .NET framework 4.5.1

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319

SchUseStrongCrypto = 1
```

But this isn't the case when we test, it still uses TLS 1.0. We've also tried installing IISCrypto and enabled all the protocols (TLS 1.0,1.1,1.2), but this fails also (restarting the server included). IISCrypto creates all the correct keys here, but no luck:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\
```

What **DOES** work, is simply installing .NET Framework 4.6.1 instead. But in this situation we can't upgrade. What actions do we need to take to enable TLS 1.2 for .NET 4.5.1?

Comment: Anything found ? i have same issue but using .net framework 4.5 and try to connecto magento soap 1.2 , any solution ?

Answer (score 5):

Did you make it the default protocol? Else it might be supported but not the default :

```
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: This may be the case, but would require a code change to every single app I guess?

Comment: @FBryant87 That would yes, i don't know if it can be done in config as i only had to worry about it on a single app so far. You said you enabled all the protocols (1.0,1.1,1.2) what happens if you only enable 1.2? Could Simply be the negociation defaults to 1.0